# Can't write to excel using C#?

Tags: c#

I am writing a very simple program. It runs without any errors. But nothing is written into the Excel file. Am I wrong somewhere?

```
  using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

  // I already add this reference into my project

  public Write()
  {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\KKK.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        // This is all I want to write to my Excel file

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "input";

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\KQ" + ThoiGian(), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlApp);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].value = "input";
```

Comment: xlApp.Visible = True will show the sheet. Comment out the code that closes the workbook. Visually check if data has been written

Comment: Still nothing Tarik . I used to write like this and they all work fine until today . Something must be wrong somewhere...

Comment: It works on another PC just fine. Very nice guess Tarik. I still have no idea whats going on with my PC. thanks for your help though !

Comment: Try your code in a vbscript to determine if it is a .net specific issue.